# Почему кто-то ставит <br>, а кто-то <br />?

Tags: html, html5

Заметил, что кто-то использует `<br>`, а кто-то `<br />`. В чём разница и зачем ставить лишний слэш?

Comment: `<br />` - это вариант написания спецификации `XHTML`, `<br>` - `HTML`.

Comment: Так исторически сложилось. В HTML5 оба варианта допустимы и равнозначны.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для html валидный вариант - `<br>`

Для xhtml - `<br/>`

Смело используйте `<br>`.

Comment: Для HTML5 валидны оба варианта, не вводите людей в заблуждение и смело используйте `<br/>`.

Comment: Я сильно подозреваю, что в половине этих роликов пишут на React (jsx) и там можно только `<br/>`

Comment: "Для HTML5 валидны оба варианта" в то то и дело, что для HTML 5.